# Does gulp preprocess support else branching

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, logical-operators, gulp-preprocess

So [gulp-preprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-preprocess) allows to define [variable dependant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23119501/875020) source code during gulp compilation, the syntax is as follows (for e.g. HTML)

`<!-- @if NODE_ENV='production' -->
  <script src="some/production/lib/like/analytics.js"></script> 
 <!-- @endif -->`

But is there also a way to specify an `else` branch?

Simply using `<!-- @else -->` doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

Since `gulp-preprocess` uses [preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/preprocess#directive-syntax), i looked there and found [no](https://github.com/jsoverson/preprocess/issues/33) `else` directive ([yet](https://github.com/jsoverson/preprocess/pull/121)). Bummer.